# How do I set X Tics in to show in kilobytes?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of CSV data where it is a range of data from 2000 - 2000000 bytes, say, and I want to plot every single one of these points. I however don't want it to say 2e6 for my data but rather just 2, so I can set my x-axis title to "megabytes".

That is, how do automatically override the visible text on the x axis bar (via some sort of formula relating to the underlying data?) using gnuplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arithmetically manipulate data in the [using](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-13400034.1.9) directive. If you have a data file `Data.csv`:

```
3.7567e+06
7.7169e+06
9.8955e+06
6.0108e+06
2.1852e+06
```

you can plot this with this script:

```
set boxwidth 0.6 relative
set style fill solid
set ylabel "Size in MB"
plot "Data.csv" u 0:($1/1e6) with boxes
```

Note the `($1/1e6)` using directive. The `$1` references the first column of the data file. The brackets are mandatory!

You end up with a plot like this:

[image]

If you have data ranging though many orders of magnitude, maybe using a [logarithmic scaling](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-19900043.33) would be interesting to think about.